# Switching to new format of upgrade scripts in magento

Tags: magento

Current version of my extension hosted on magentocommerce is `v1.0.0`, and right now I have the install script named as `mysql4-install-1.0.php`. Notice only `1.0` and not `1.0.0`.

Now I am about to release a small bug fix `v1.0.1` and also thought of switching to the new nomenclature of upgrade scripts.

Should I just rename `mysql4-install-1.0.php` to `mymodule_setup/install-1.0.0.php` and then add a new `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php` under `mymodule_setup` directory?

How do I make the transition without breaking old installs using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately renaming your file to install-1.0.0.php WILL run the script again.  All version checking is run through php's version_compare() function.  What this means is that 1 < 1.0 < 1.0.0.

I would leave the install file as-is and make your upgrade script upgrade-1.0-1.0.1.php

By leaving the install file the same you now have the following files and no re-run files:

```
mysql4-install-1.0.php
upgrade-1.0-1.0.1.php

(and in the future):
upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php
```

There is no true reason to go back and rename any install files or adjust them in anyway if they are working on a current instance.

When all else fails reference the code base to figure out what is happening.  See file: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php

Comment: The `version_compare()` info is correct, but the install info is not correct. Once a module is registered in `core_resource` the application *will not* run another install script for that module ever, only upgrade scripts will be run.

Comment: Cool that makes sense but what about having the files in a directory named `mmymodule_setup`?

Comment: @Ashfame: I stand corrected by Ben. I'm not 100% sure what you're asking about the mmymodule_setup, but I suspect changing the folder name will make the install script run again.  The core_resource pulls its module name from the setup node inside of the <resources> node.  If you change the <mymodule_setup> inside the <resources> node to something like <mynamespace_mymodule_setup> the database will see it as a new resource installation and run the install script a second time.  Reference the method "applyAllUpdates()" in /BASE_MAGENTO_ENT_1_12/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php

Comment: Sorry I thought we also need to move the files in the directory, but they already are there. Your answer helped me get there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter wether you rename the file or not. If you rename it and the shop runs on 1.0(.0) the install script doesn't run, if it is not installed yet, it will run. Both is ok.

install-1.0.0 and install-1.0 is not the same, but if the extension is installed, it won't run a second install script ;-)

If you change the name of the old file, you have to add two upgrade scripts:

```
upgrade-1.0-1.0.1.php
```

and

```
upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php
```

I'm not sure, but this is the way I expect it.